# Devexpress c# how to insert MultiSelectedItems(checkboxrowselect) from grid to Database

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have gridview which is bound to the dataset and trying to insert `multipleselectedrows(CheckBoxRowSelect)` to my database but everytime I failed. I tried many different ways but there is no result. My codes are for insert:

```
int[] selectedrows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
for (int i = 0; i < selectedrows.Length; i++)
{
   string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE1(COL1,COL2,COL3) SELECT " + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL4") + "," + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL5") + ",'" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL6")" FROM dbo.TABLE2 WHERE COL4=" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL4") + " AND COL5=" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL5") + "";

   connection(sql); // sqlconnection and sqlcommand metod
}
```

Comment: What is inside these variables once you debug?

Comment: i couldnt follow you what you mean by variables.if u mean gridview cell values; i got string format values and int format values

Comment: If you set a breakpoint before making the actual connection you should see whether the right values are going into your SQL-statement/what SQL statement is being generated. That way you can find out if the error is with your getRowCellValue-Calls or with your generated SQL. Btw. you should read up on SQL Injection.

Comment: Everything seems fine,when trying to execute to query it's fail.I almost get crazy with that problem where i making mistake couldn't figure it out

Comment: @enigmad87 Can you show the query that you are trying to execute?

Comment: @nempoBu4 it's already on code snippet up there i use exacly the same query

Comment: @enigmad87 Your code snippet have errors, so what is the query?

Comment: basicly my query like this: "INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE1(col1,col2,col3) SELECT col4,"+gridview1.GetRowCellValue(i,"col5")+","+GetRowCellValue(i,"col6")+" FROM dbo.TABL2";

Comment: Actualy this query inserting some rows but not what i selected from the gridview,for example i'm selecting 2 rows and clicking button,it's inserting irrelevent rows and inserting couple of times

Comment: @enigmad87 Why do you don't want to use `"INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE1(COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES (" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL4") + "," + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL5") + ",'" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL6") + "')"`?

Comment: there is no reason just tried to insert selectedrows to database, this is the problem that i dont know how to fix this and what i need to do

Comment: by the way i already tried to use parameterized command resul is the same,  command insertint first rows which is not i selected

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because you read your values NOT from the selected rows.

This should work:

```
int[] selectedrows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
foreach (int i in selectedrows)
{
   string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE1(COL1,COL2,COL3) SELECT " + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL4") + "," + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL5") + ",'" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL6")" FROM dbo.TABLE2 WHERE COL4=" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL4") + " AND COL5=" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "COL5") + "";

   connection(sql); // sqlconnection and sqlcommand metod
}
```

Comment: I solved it long time ago :) My mistake was a dumy :) just used gridview1.GetRowCellValue(selectedrows[i],"col4")
anyway Thank you for advise dude